# iPad & Windows Excel client doesn't see App Catalog Add-ins

Tags: excel-addins, office-addins, officedev

I've got two add-ins deployed to my O365 tenancy's App Catalog site. Both work just fine and can be added to workbooks in Excel Online with no issues.

However, even though I'm logged into my O365 account in both Excel 2013 on Windows & Excel on the iPad (both fully patched & current), I see nothing in my app catalog (under My Add-ins). No group policy setup for my tenant / Azure AD... no machines joined to domains...

While I know there's a registry hack you can use on Windows to get it working, what reason would Add-ins not appear listed on either client from the App Catalog?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem with the Windows client is that you have to first configure Excel to Trust the URL of the app catalog. That's buried within Options => Trust Center => Trusted Addins (doing that from memory so think it's correct). You then plug in the url to your App Catalog site in O365 & restart Excel.

For Excel iPad, you can side load it via iTunes...